# Play diplomacy offline

Tags: diplomacy

I am with a group of friends and we want to play Diplomacy. However we don't have the map, or a printer.

So I was thinking that maybe there is some app or website in which there is the map and we can all play on. However if I search online for Diplomacy, all the websites are online multiplayer versions of Diplomacy. I am looking for something that serves just like a board game version, where the moves for all the players are done manually.

Comment: This is an odd question - you're basically asking how to play a board game without buying the board game. Would you ask the same question for Catan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use [jDip](http://jdip.sourceforge.net/). It is easy to use, and provides several maps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many places to play Diplomacy online

- [Play Diplomacy](http://www.playdiplomacy.com)
- [BackStabbr](http://www.backstabbr.com)
- [webDiplomacy](http://webdiplomacy.net)
- [Stabbeurfou](http://www.stabbeurfou.org)
- [DPJudge](http://uk.diplom.org)

  **Edit**
  I didn't read that well enough. You want fully manual games. Well then you can try [Vassal](http://www.vassalengine.org/wiki/Module:Diplomacy) or maybe Tabletop Simulator I don't know if you can play Tabletop Simulator on one computer if that's one of your goals but in both cases you should have full control of everything. As a matter of fact you could do play by email games by emailing Vassal save-states but I don't have a lot of experience in that.

Comment: The OP asked for an offline solution ;-).

Comment: Oh snap my mistake. That explains why none of the many many online implementations had already been suggested. That's on me and my reading comprehensions. -- E-- actually it looks liek not so much offline but manual movements.